# Delete arbitrary text from a string in LUA language

Tags: string, lua, streaming

I am trying to write a lua program to send a gcode file to grbl
I have saved all the lines of the gcode file in a table.

The buffer in grbl accepts 250 characters.
I have put each line of the Gcode file into a string with a \n at the end of each line:

```
Mystr=Mystr..gc_line[l_cnt].."\n"
```

I do this until the number of characters in the string does not exceed 250 characters
Additionally I have stored the length of each line separately in another table.

Then I send mystr string to grbl via serial

At this moment grbl sends a feedback with the text ok after receiving each gcode block.

After receiving the ok, I need to subtract the length of that line from the length of mystr (which was 250 characters) to create space to send a new line.

It is also necessary to remove the corresponding line from the mystr string so that the lines that have already been sent will not be re-sent in the next transmissions.

My reason for appending each line of gcode in mystr is that every time mystr is sent to grbl, the grbl buffer is filled so that the motors move smoothly in high speed machines like laser machines.

The part that I have a problem with is actually the deletion of the sent line that has received the OK feedback from grbl, from the mystr string.

Comment: string.sub....?

Comment: I would be grateful if you could explain your point with an example

Comment: string.sub lets you take part of a string, for example, starting at the 100th character

Comment: documented here https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html